# How to test if a pane exists in tmux

Tags: shell-script, tmux

I'm new to tmux, i want to know how to test if a pane is closed or not by pane_id.

I'm using following script to do the job right now:

```
tmux display-message -p -t %21 >/dev/null && echo 123
```

It works, but i'm not sure it's the right way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your way with `display-message` is kinda workaround. There's another command *designed* for what you want. From `man 1 tmux`:

> `has-session [-t target-session]`
>   (alias: `has`)
>   Report an error and exit with `1` if the specified session does not exist.  If it does exist, exit with `0`.

It's not immediately obvious that `target-session` may be a session, window or pane. In your case `%21` refers to a pane, use this:

```
tmux has-session -t %21 2>/dev/null && echo 123
```

Note syntaxes that also specify session and window should work as well, e.g. `$0:@1.%21` or `@1.%21` (keep in mind `$0` needs to be single-quoted in a shell). Use them if you need to test for a pane that possibly exists in some non-current session/window.

Comment: This does work but I don't really recommend relying on this behaviour, has-session is only intended to accept a session target.

Answer (score 1):

That's fine. Or you can use eg lsp -F'#{pane_id}'|grep -q ^%21$.